# Programmatically autolayout not centering vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios8, autolayout

I want to use autolayout to center a view vertically and horizontally but somehow I'm having troubles doing so. I'm running on iOS8 simulator and iOS8 device. There are two versions of code which I have tried and none of them works. Below are the snippets:

First let's allocate the view we're using:

```
UIView *inputView = UIView.new; //Don't hate me for the dot syntax :)
inputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
inputView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;

[self.view addSubview:inputView];
```

Attempt #1:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]; //Center the view horizontally
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f]; //And make it have the same width as the view
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:0.0f constant:260.0f]; //Force exactly 260pts view height
[inputView addConstraint:constraint]; //If I add it to self.view it's the same thing

constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:0.5f constant:0.0f]; //And try to center it vertically - DOES NOT WORK... wtf
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

Seems like a perfectly legitimate piece of code to me. But NOPE.

Attempt #2. It's basically the same thing with less lines of code.

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[inputView(>=320)]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(inputView)];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[inputView(260)]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(inputView)];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Now this one does not work either. I mean it does center the view horizontally but when I add the vertical constraint I do get a warning telling me that I suck at auto layout. It says its unable to satisfy all the constraints. More specifically:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408be00 UIView:0x174197010.top == UIView:0x174196da0.topMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408bdb0 V:[UIView:0x174197010(260)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408bd60 UIView:0x174196da0.bottomMargin == UIView:0x174197010.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008a000 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x174196da0(667)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17408bd60 UIView:0x174196da0.bottomMargin == UIView:0x174197010.bottom>
```

I'm not sure how do I fix this. Below are the pictures of the results I get from attempts #1 and #2.

[image: Layout issues]

How can I fix it?

Comment: lol with the dot syntax. let me guess: your UIView extension is called UIView+Swift!

Comment: Nope it's actually all ObjC :) This was a very lame thing introduced by Apple a long time ago I think. It doesn't show in the syntax completion but compiles nevertheless. Try it out. If find it cleaner than `[UIView new]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting vertical constraint, you made the multiplier to 0.5f which is causing this. Make it to 1.0f as you had it for Horizontal constraint.

```
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:inputView
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:self.view
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                           constant:0.0f];
```

Comment: Ahhh of course! I've been thinking "okay this needs to be half the entire height" and that's where that `0.5` got from. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You constantly redefine `constraint`. You need to have something like `xconstraint`, `yconstraint`, `wconstraint`, `hconstraint`. Then add each constraint to self.view or `[self.view addConstraints:@[xconstraint, yconstraint,...];`

You may also need to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];`

UPDATE

The multiplier on your Y constraint needs to be 1.0, not 0.5.

Comment: No this is not necessary. Since `NSLayoutConstraint *constraint` is just a pointer to a constraint and as soon as I add a constraint to a view (ie. `addConstraint:`) that view holds a strong reference to it. So when doing `constraint = [new constraint]` I'm merely just changing the pointer.

As for the `layoutIfNeeded` it does not work.

Comment: what happens if you also call `setNeedsLayout` before `layoutIfNeeded`?

Comment: updated with answer. You were a victim of copy and paste or something.